# Localized soundex() database query

Tags: mariadb

The SOUNDEX() function checks whether words are similar in sound and allows for misspellings to be included in a select.

How I understand it though it that it uses English as a basis for the word sounds it generates, in other languages this can lead to mismatches due to words/vowels etc.. being pronounced differently.

Is there a way to have SOUNDEX() behave with for example German or Dutch or any other language? Or am I misunderstanding how it works and will it work just as properly as with English?

Comment: You would have to write a custom algorithm for a language, no `SOUNDEX()` will only work "correctly" with english but still you can get irrelevant results that names that clearly differ in pronunciation, have the same soundex code

Comment: Even for English, Soundex() is rather lame.  I suggest you look for a different function.